# Mapbox multiple If statement in a Var

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to change Mapbox marker colors according to a column tag. I have 3 separate columns Apple, Banana, and Orange I would like to associate that tag with a different marker color. This is my code so far. As of now, no markers show on the map.

```html
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker;({
          if (row["Apple"]) {
            color: 'blue';
          }
          else if (row["Banana"]) { 
            color: 'orange';
          }
          else (row["Orange"]) {
          color: 'yellow';
        }
        })
```

Comment: Remove this semicolon: `new mapboxgl.Marker;` should be `new mapboxgl.Marker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ternary expression like so (also remove the semicolon preceding your `(` and fix your syntax:

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
  color: row["Apple"] ? "blue" : (row["Banana"] ? "orange" : "yellow")
});
```

Comment: Yup, it did the trick. Much appreciated for the enlightenment.

Comment: No worries @Nick - feel free to accept if it solved your problem.